# Remaking request to the function

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-functions

I need to turn this request to the function

```
SELECT object_id, brigade_code, date_and_time
FROM purpose
WHERE date_and_time BETWEEN '2022-06-15 16:20:23' AND '2022-10-03 18:12:45';
```

My best attempt

```
Create function report_for_period (date_from timestamp, date_to timestamp)
returns int
language 'plpgsql'
as
$$
    begin
        SELECT date_and_time::timestamp
        from purpose
        WHERE date_and_time between $1 and $2;
    end;
$$

select report_for_period ('2022-06-15 16:20:23'::timestamp,'2022-10-03 18:12:45'::timestamp)
```

And this gives me this, after SELECT command:

> ERROR: ERROR: There is no destination for result data in the request
> HINT: If you need to discard SELECT results, use PERFORM.
> CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function report_for_period (timestamp without time zone,timestamp without time zone), line 3, SQL statement

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+There+is+no+destination+for+result+data+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: Even if you use `PERFORM` that will get you to the next error which is you don't have a `RETURN ...;`. Also you have `returns int` and do not have the afore mentioned `RETURN` or any `integer` value to return if you did.